# jquery image rollover behaviour

Tags: jquery, image, thumbnails, behavior

I have the following code that allows a thumbnails src attr to replace the image in a main image window.

```
        $(document).ready(function(){   
            var originalimg = $('#imageMain img').attr('src');
                $(".subImage").hover(function(){
                        var currentimg = $(this).attr('src');
                    $('.mainImage').fadeOut(function () {
                    $('.mainImage').attr('src', currentimg).fadeIn();
                        });
                    },function(){
                            $('.mainImage').fadeOut(function() {
                                $('.mainImage').attr('src', originalimg).fadeIn();
                            })
                            });
            });
```

Currently the behaviour does the following:
1. hover over - main image fades to white, then fades into the sub image. 2. mouse out - main image fades to white, then is replaced with the original.

What I really need instead of the 'white' transition in between the 2 image states, I want them to sort of overlap (so one fades out as the other fades in) -

is this possible?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can not roatate the image sequentially with fadeout/fadein.You have to make the transition in a alternative way.I have wrote the whole code for you:

```
    <head>
    <title>jQuery Image Rotator</title>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $("#photoshow").hover(function() {
        setInterval("rotateImages()", 2000); // set the interval time as your wish
    });

    function rotateImages() {
        var oCurPhoto = $('#photoShow div.current');
        var oNxtPhoto = oCurPhoto.next();
        if (oNxtPhoto.length == 0)
            oNxtPhoto = $('#photoShow div:first');

        oCurPhoto.removeClass('current').addClass('previous');
        oNxtPhoto.css({ opacity: 0.0 }).addClass('current').animate({ opacity: 1.0 }, 1000,
            function() {
                oCurPhoto.removeClass('previous');
            });
    }
</script>
       <style type="text/css">
         #photoShow {
        height:400px;
         width:400px;
         }
      #photoShow div {
        position:absolute;
        z-index: 0;
         }
      #photoShow div.previous {
        z-index: 1;
         }
         #photoShow div.current {
          z-index: 2;
           }
</style>
    </head>
  <body>
    <div id="photoShow">
       <div class="current">
        <img src="images/Grass.jpg" alt="Photo Gallery" width="400" height="400" class="gallery" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="images/Leaf.jpg" alt="Photo Gallery" width="400" height="400" class="gallery" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="images/Spring.jpg" alt="Photo Gallery" width="400" height="400" class="gallery" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="images/Water.jpg" alt="Photo Gallery" width="400" height="400" class="gallery" />
    </div>
     </div>
   </body>
    </html>
```

It will make a transition of image one by one.Replace with proper class, id name and image url.Hope it helps !

Comment: Thanks, I sort of see what it's meant to do, but I can't get ti working. it just shows grass.jpg.